# Selenium Module Not Found

Tags: python, macos, selenium

[image]
I am trying to use Selenium.  I did not have it installed before, I used pip3 to install it, the install was successful.  I opened python3 and imported Selenium and it said Module not found.  Anyone have any idea what could be the problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pip3 may not be using the same python3 version your are running.

Try installing it this way:

```
python3 -m pip install selenium
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you should be using 'import selenium'. 'import webdriver' maybe?
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html

Comment: I tried that Sir, It still says module not found. Any other ideas.

Comment: Yes sir I have, Still says  No module named 'selenium'.

Comment: Hmm, if it installed correctly, then really dont know sorry mate

Comment: You don't see anything incorrect with my download do you tho sir ?

Comment: It looks like in installed correctly. Hmm. Have you Googled "ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'selenium'" and looked at the other posts on Stackoverflow from people who have had the same problem?